# Read a socket direclty from InputStream or from BufferedReader?

Tags: java, sockets

My goal is to read the n number of `bytes` from a `Socket`.

Is it better to directly read from the `InputStream`, or wrap it into a `BufferedReader`?

Throughout the net you find both approaches, but none states which to use when.

```
Socket socket;
is = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

char[] buffer = new char[CONTENT_LENGTH];

//what is better?
is.read(buffer);
br.read(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to "read the n number of bytes" there is little point creating a character `Reader` from your input as this might mean the nth byte is part way into a character - and assuming that the stream is character based.

Since JDK11 there is handy call for reading n bytes:

```
byte[] input = is.readNBytes(n);
```

If n is small and you repeat the above often, consider reading the stream using one of `bis = new BufferedInputStream(is)`, `in.transferTo(out)` or `len  = read(byteArray)` which may be more effective for longer streams.

Comment: In my opinion "there is little point" is euphemism for "you should/can not". There is almost zero chance that reading bytes through a Reader is the good abstraction, even though it may work : it is undefined why or when it would, which is pretty much not what you expect from software at any point. In that sense, I find the expression polite, but almost misleading, I would be more assertive about it.